# How to match numbers ranging from 1 to n with regex?

Tags: html, regex, validation, input

I want to **validate**, using HTML pattern attribute (so i can get the notification), a numeric string that must only contain numbers ranging from **1 to 400** (I can allow 001).

I tried the following pattern but i'm missing a few *many*

```
^([1-3][0-9]{0,2}|400)$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one `([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|400)$`

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,2} matches any number between 1–999
|400 limit upto 400
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
^(0?0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|[1-3][0-9][0-9]|400)$
```

This will match 1-400 with optional leading zeroes.

Comment: The | operator acts like an OR. It doesn't modify the other expression preceding it (it doesn't limit it to 400).

0?0?[1-9] matches 1 or 01 or 001;
0?[1-9][0-9] matches 10 or 010;
[1-3][0-9][0-9] matches 100 or 399;
400 matches 400, and nothing else.

The | operator tells it to match the first OR the second OR the third OR the fourth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex

```
let re = /^([1-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]|400)$/;
re.test(input);

### verification
let regex = /^([1-3]?[0-9]?[0-9]|400)$/;

let i = 1;
while(regex.test(i)){
  i += 1;
}
console.log(i); // outputs 401
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s an old question, but the answer isn’t satisfactory. the regex `([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|400)$` is the same as `([1-9][0-9]{0,2})$`, meaning that it’ll match anything from 1 to 999.

`|` on regex is simply an `OR` registrator, so values above 400 will match on the first category.

To do a regex ranging from `1` to `n`, you always need to break it down to the previous decimal place.

For the case of 400, for instance: We would need to first cover the bases from 1 to 99 as follows:

`[1-9][0-9]{0,1}`: This means that we want anything that ranges from 1-9 and then anything after that that ranges from 0-9 up to 1 time.

Then, we cover anything from 100 to 399 as follows:
`[1-3][0-9]{2}`: This means that we accept any number starting with 1, 2 or 3 followed by 2 other numbers than can range from 0 to 9. Values such as 100, 243 or 399 are on this range, but 400, 600 aren’t.

and lastly, compare with `400`.

Now, we join them with our `OR` element over regexes: `|`:

`/([1-9][0-9]{0,1}|[1-3][0-9]{2}|400)$/` (note the `$` at the end to guarantee that’s the end of line or string to avoid greedy matching, such as picking 45 as the two first characters on 450).

There’s several sites to test your regexes and I strongly recommend testing them before using it. [regex101](https://regex101.com/) has a better assorting of languages to test your regex (different programming languages may have slightly different interpretations on some rules), but [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) is also a good website to test them out.