# Is it possible to have a general regex formula for range from 1 to n?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a generic regex formula to find if a number is below a certain limit

I've already tried for ranges like 0 - 100 like in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525090/how-to-match-numbers-ranging-from-1-to-n-with-regex)  though I couldn't find an explanation on how to find a generic approach given a variable n for instance.

Comment: Sure: `regex = '(' + '|'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)) + ')'` Won't win any awards for speed, though. :)

Comment: Surely it would be better to search for `\d+` and then reject the ones you don't want in the code.  Remember that the regex processor has to check all of those alternatives at every character.

Comment: Do you want this for literally any range from potentially -X to +Y or for any number of less than N digits.  Requiring M digits or less would be really simple.  For other numbers it might be easier and faster to catch all possible matching numbers as groups and then verify them separately with numeric comparison instead of regex

Comment: Before getting into this: *Why* do you need a regex? There's almost always a better solution. I get it if you're working with some limited interface that's not a true programming language, but almost always the correct approach would be to call `int` on the string and then do the range check with the result (with a `try:`/`except ValueError:` if you have some reasonable way to handle strings that aren't legal `int`s at all).

Comment: I've tried the following  `return r'(' + '|^'.join(str(i) + "$" for i in range(1, n)) + ')' if n > 1 else "[^\-a-zA-Z0-9]"`, eventually it timed out, yet an interesting solution I'm looking for a more efficient one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

- Start with the digit strings of the lengths that are always valid, i.e. the ones that are strictly shorter than the limit. `[1-9][0-9]{0,n⁻⁻}`, where *n⁻⁻* is two less than the length of the upper bound. (If *n* = 1, skip this.)
- Then add the range of single-digit prefixes where all values of the upper bound’s length are valid: `[1-b⁻][0-9]{n⁻⁻}`, where *b⁻* is the digit before the first digit. (If the first digit is 1, or if *n* = 1, skip this. If *n* = 2, don’t bother emitting `[0-9]{0}`.)
- Finally, match strings starting with the remaining valid digit: `b(?:…)`, where `…` is a slight variation on these last two steps applied recursively to match fixed-width digit strings of length *n* − 1 (if *n* = 1, `…` is empty and we’re done, so don’t bother emitting `(?:)`) in the new range starting at 0 and ending with the upper bound obtained by removing the first digit from the original upper bound:

  - Start with the range of single-digit prefixes where all values of the upper bound’s length are valid: `[0-b⁻][0-9]{n⁻⁻}`
  - And match strings starting with the remaining valid digit: `b(?:…)`.

Typical formatting like leading zeros (`0*`)/signs is safe to add to the start of regexes assembled following this approach, in the sense of not having any catastrophic backtracking issues.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} bound - Upper bound, inclusive.
 */
const integers1ToNRegex = (bound) => {
  if (typeof bound !== "string" || !/^\d+$/.test(bound)) {
    throw new TypeError("invalid non-negative integer decimal string");
  }
  bound = bound.replace(/^0+/, "");
  if (bound === "") {
    return "(?!)";
  }
  if (bound.length === 1) {
    return `[1-${bound}]`;
  }
  let regex = `[1-9][0-9]{0,${bound.length - 2}}`;
  if (+bound.charAt(0) > 1) {
    regex += `|[1-${+bound.charAt(0) - 1}][0-9]{${bound.length - 1}}`;
  }
  regex += `|${bound.charAt(0)}`;
  for (let i = 1; i < bound.length - 1; i++) {
    const digit = +bound.charAt(i);
    const indent = "\n" + "  ".repeat(i);
    regex += `(?:${indent}`;
    if (digit > 0) {
      regex += `[0-${digit - 1}][0-9]{0,${bound.length - 1 - i}}|`;
    }
    regex += digit;
  }
  regex += `[0-${bound.at(-1)}]`;
  return regex + ")".repeat(bound.length - 2);
};

const boundInput = document.getElementById("bound");
const regexOutput = document.getElementById("regex");

const update = () => {
  if (boundInput.reportValidity()) {
    regexOutput.value = integers1ToNRegex(boundInput.value);
  } else {
    regexOutput.value = "";
  }
};

boundInput.addEventListener("input", update, {passive: true});
update();
```

```css
#regex {
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="bound" min="1" value="1234" required>

<output id="regex" for="bound"></output>
```

Comment: How would you do that in a single regex formula? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @der_Loewen: What is a “regex formula”?

Comment: I mean a single regular expression, if that's not too much, your answer was very interesting, I was looking more for one like the @Nick ODell 's, I don't know why it got so flagged though, it's a correct answer anyway.

Comment: @der_Loewen: This produces a single regular expression, like Nick ODell’s comment. Not sure what you mean by flagged.